# Get phonemes from any word in Python NLTK or other modules?

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

Python NLTK has cmudict that spits out phonemes of recognized words. For example 'see' -> [u'S', u'IY1'], but for words that are not recognized it gives an error. For example 'seasee' -> error.

```
import nltk

arpabet = nltk.corpus.cmudict.dict()

for word in ('s', 'see', 'sea', 'compute', 'comput', 'seesea'):
    try:
        print arpabet[word][0]
    except Exception as e:
        print e

#Output
[u'EH1', u'S']
[u'S', u'IY1']
[u'S', u'IY1']
[u'K', u'AH0', u'M', u'P', u'Y', u'UW1', u'T']
'comput'
'seesea'
```

Is any there any module that doesn't have that limitation but able to find/guess phonemes of any real or made-up words?

If there is none, is there any way I can program it out? I am thinking about doing loops to test increasing portion of the word. For example in 'seasee', the first loop takes "s", next loop takes 'se', and third takes 'sea'... etc and run the cmudict. Though the problem is I don't know how to signal it's the right phoneme to consider. For example, both 's' and 'sea' in 'seasee' will output some valid phonemes.

Working progress:

```
import nltk

arpabet = nltk.corpus.cmudict.dict()

for word in ('s', 'see', 'sea', 'compute', 'comput', 'seesea', 'darfasasawwa'):
    try:
        phone = arpabet[word][0]
    except:
        try:
            counter = 0
            for i in word:
                substring = word[0:1+counter]
                counter += 1
                try:
                    print substring, arpabet[substring][0]
                except Exception as e:
                    print e
        except Exception as e:
            print e

#Output
c [u'S', u'IY1']
co [u'K', u'OW1']
com [u'K', u'AA1', u'M']
comp [u'K', u'AA1', u'M', u'P']
compu [u'K', u'AA1', u'M', u'P', u'Y', u'UW0']
comput 'comput'
s [u'EH1', u'S']
se [u'S', u'AW2', u'TH', u'IY1', u'S', u'T']
see [u'S', u'IY1']
sees [u'S', u'IY1', u'Z']
seese [u'S', u'IY1', u'Z']
seesea 'seesea'
d [u'D', u'IY1']
da [u'D', u'AA1']
dar [u'D', u'AA1', u'R']
darf 'darf'
darfa 'darfa'
darfas 'darfas'
darfasa 'darfasa'
darfasas 'darfasas'
darfasasa 'darfasasa'
darfasasaw 'darfasasaw'
darfasasaww 'darfasasaww'
darfasasawwa 'darfasasawwa'
```

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same issue, and I solved it by partitioning unknown recursively (see `wordbreak`)

```
import nltk
from functools import lru_cache
from itertools import product as iterprod

try:
    arpabet = nltk.corpus.cmudict.dict()
except LookupError:
    nltk.download('cmudict')
    arpabet = nltk.corpus.cmudict.dict()

@lru_cache()
def wordbreak(s):
    s = s.lower()
    if s in arpabet:
        return arpabet[s]
    middle = len(s)/2
    partition = sorted(list(range(len(s))), key=lambda x: (x-middle)**2-x)
    for i in partition:
        pre, suf = (s[:i], s[i:])
        if pre in arpabet and wordbreak(suf) is not None:
            return [x+y for x,y in iterprod(arpabet[pre], wordbreak(suf))]
    return None
```

Comment: Recursion on the word boundaries

Comment: Best answer, thank you. Also helps to merge the output into a single list:
`phonemes = list(itertools.chain.fromiterable(wordbreak(word)))`

Answer (score 3):

Try pronouncing module:

https://pronouncing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Sample:

> pronouncing.phones_for_word("word")

i hope this works :)

Comment: I don't think `pronouncing` works for words not in the CMU Dictionary. e.g. a word like "sorceress" doesn't return anything. 

See this Jupyter Notebook for an interactive example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16l67HFKLBvQhHeeX8qpqacjc5DOLVg0V?usp=sharing

Comment: guess i dont have anything to say after i tested it XD

Comment: it might be a good idea to update your original post to reflect that, lest future readers be misled.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LOGIOS Lexicon Tool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lextool.html). This was the output for your example:

```
S   EH S
SEE S IY
SEA S IY
COMPUTE K AH M P Y UW T
COMPUT  K AH M P UH T
SEESEA  S IY S IY
```

I'm not aware of any python implementation, you can try to implement yourself, or call the [perl code](https://github.com/skerit/cmusphinx/blob/master/logios/Tools/MakeDict/make_pronunciation.pl) using `subprocess.call`

Comment: Thanks but it is possible to get it implemented in Python? Everything I have is in Python and I would like to automate in a script as much as possible.

Comment: I'm not aware of any python implementation, you can try to implement yourself, or call the [perl code](https://github.com/skerit/cmusphinx/blob/master/logios/Tools/MakeDict/make_pronunciation.pl) using `subprocess.call`. Edited answer

Comment: You can also use jython (haven't tested it)
http://source.cet.uct.ac.za/svn/people/smarquard/sphinx/scripts/word2phones.py

Comment: Sorry but could you elaborate more (maybe a simple code example) on how to use these other languages' codes in Python using subprocess.call? It's way over my head.

Comment: The `subprocess` module allows you to run os commands from python, as if  you ran them from the shell. e.g. `import subprocess; subprocess.call["echo", "hello"])`. Anyhow, I think it'd be simpler to run the jython script, as you already know python

Comment: I feel like a complete noob >.<. OK, I have downloaded from your links. I first saved the http://source.cet.uct.ac.za/svn/people/smarquard/sphinx/scripts/word2phones.py file in my computer. Then downloaded and extracted the jar files from sourceforge-freetts. Then in the .py file I change the root into the corresponding directory pointing to the jar files. But when I run the .py, I get this error: ImportError: No module named com.sun.speech.freetts.lexicon

Comment: @KubiK, do you understand what Jython is? It's a [different python engine](https://www.python.org/download/alternatives/), and it knows about `.jar` files. You can't use them with your regular "C Python".

Comment: The tool is based on a CMUdict too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use g2p library

INSTALLATION:

```
pip install g2p_en
```

OR

```
python setup.py install
```

Usage:

```
from g2p_en import G2p

texts = ["using g2p"]
g2p = G2p()
for text in texts:
    out = g2p(text)
    print(out)
```

Comment: It's better to format your codes in questions and answer for better readabilty

Answer (score 0):

I just completed Dunno's answer. By using this the following code, you will get exactly the same result as you can get from [LOGIOS Lexicon Tool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lextool.html)
, which is based on **CMUdict**.

```
import re
import pronouncing
text = "april is the cruelest month breeding lilacs out of the dead"
words = text.split()
WordToPhn=[]
for word in words:
    pronunciation_list = pronouncing.phones_for_word(word)[0] # choose the first version of the phoneme
    WordToPhn.append(pronunciation_list)

SentencePhn='  '.join(WordToPhn) 
Output = re.sub(r'\d+', '', SentencePhn) #Remove the digits in phonemes

#SentencePhn: EY1 P R AH0 L  IH1 Z  DH AH0  K R UW1 L AH0 S T  M AH1 N TH  B R IY1 D IH0 NG  L AY1 L AE2 K S  AW1 T  AH1 V  DH AH0  D EH1 D

#Output:EY P R AH L  IH Z  DH AH  K R UW L AH S T  M AH N TH  B R IY D IH NG  L AY L AE K S  AW T  AH V  DH AH  D EH D
```

I used two spaces between each word's phonemes. If you want to have only one space like LOGIOS Lexicon Tool, you can change it to one space here:

```
SentencePhn='  '.join(WordToPhn)
```