# Word to phonemes converter for slangs and made up words in Python

Tags: nlp, nltk, phoneme

I currently use NLTK to convert words to phonemes in python. This works well for words in the library, but for slangs and made up words, NLTK doesn't work. E.g. words like
"whasup"
"dawg"

Is there a library that does a best guess at the phonemes of slangs?

There seems to be [this](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lextool.html) tool but there isn't a python library for it.

Comment: The business end of the tool you found relies on either a web service at http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/tools/lmtool.2.pl, or the binary available at http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/logios/Tools/MakeDict/bin/x86-nt/pronounce.exe (or linux equivalent, also compiled; see [here](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/logios/Tools/MakeDict/lib/Pronounce.pm)). There's no source for the pronouncer that I can see.

Comment: I don't know if you have seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666557/get-phonemes-from-any-word-in-python-nltk-or-other-modules) very similar question.

Comment: @alexis do you have a sample request to call the web service at  speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/tools/lmtool.2.pl ?

Comment: No. I just looked at the code. You can do the same, and/or run it and inspect the call it puts together.